# Two dangling prepositions "(...) in on."

Tags: prepositions

In the game "Fallout Shelter" there is a description of one of ingame items that caught my eye. It's about a weapon ("Armor piercing sniper rifle"), and "Vertibird" is a type of combat aircraft:

> Kill the soldier, and the Vertibird he flies **in on**.

This "in on" is giving me trouble here. **In** obviously describes relationship between the soldier and the aircraft. **On** feels like description of soldier's action, but I can't really understand what action it might be.

What is the meaning of "on" here? What rules govern such constructs?

Comment: The soldier *flies **in***; that is, he flies into the combat area or point of deplanement. He makes this flight ***on*** a Vertibird. That is *the Vertibird **on** which he flies **in***, or *the Vertibird he flies **in** **on***.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case *in* functions as an adverb and describes where the soldier flies: **in** to the field of battle.

*On* refers to the relationship between the soldier and the aircraft.

In English, there is no hard and fast rule that governs whether *in* or *on* is used with vehicles.

You can be *on* (or less commonly *in*) a train/plane/boat/ship, but only *in* a car. Well, you can be on a car, but that would mean you were on top of the car.

The entire description is also a reference to the phrase [...and the horse you rode in on.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/and_the_horse_you_rode_in_on)